# How do I restrict the type of items added to a derived class?

Tags: c#, collections, derived-class

I have DerivedClass which inherits from BaseClass.  I want to take advantage of the BaseCollection class which overrides the InsertItem method so I defined DerivedCollection and inherited from BaseCollection.  The problem is, DerivedCollection allows both DerivedClass and BaseClass types to be added.  I only want to permit DerivedClass types to be added to DerivedCollection.  What am I missing?

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public static string MyString;
}

public class BaseCollection<T> : Collection<BaseClass> where T : BaseClass
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, BaseClass item)
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that.");
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public static int MyInteger;
}

public class DerivedCollection : BaseCollection<DerivedClass>
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change `BaseCollection<T>` to inherit from `Collection<T>`, not from `Collection<BaseClass>`.
2. Change arguments of `InsertItem` appropriately.

```
public class BaseCollection<T> : Collection<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    protected override void InsertItem (int index, T item)
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only want to allow T:

```
protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
{
    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that.");
}
```

You also have to inherit from `Collection<T>` instead of `Collection<BaseClass>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to override InsertItem like so:

```
public class DerivedCollection : BaseCollection<DerivedClass>
{
protected override void InsertItem(int index, DerivedClass item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `BaseCollection` is not exclusive to `DerivedClass` or `DerivedCollection`.  Later on, I might reused `BaseClass` and `BaseCollection` in `AnotherDerivedClass` and `AnotherDerivedCollection` and `AnotherDerivedCollection` should only permit `AnotherDerivedClass` types.

Comment: Ah, so then will I have to then override all four methods (ClearItems, InsertItem, RemoveItem, and SetItem) just to force `DerivedClass`?

Comment: Actually, @Dennis_E has the answer you're looking for above. You need to change BaseCollection as per his instruction.